# major GC in JVM issue

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

JVM heap is divided into two spaces, space of old generation and space of young generation. After major GC, there will be freed space in old generation after compacting/sweep process, I am wondering whether the free space we got during major GC still belong to old generation space, or the free space of old generation could be moved to the space of young generation?

In other words, I am asking whether there is fixed size/boundary for the space of old generation and space of young generation.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hotspot, there are options for that

```
-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
```

However this still can be ignored by the VM. Its part of the dark auto tuning magic. 
For simpicity, just assume that the division betwen old and young is fixed. Same applies to eden and survivor.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a boundary between each generation, but the size of some generations maybe changeable sine the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` not same.

When to collect an object, the garbage collection mark the space as available whick the object used.

It looks like deleting a file on you disk. The OS just mark the file path unaccessible and make the space available for next store.

Generations like disk partitions, but generations can decrease or increase their's space.

Comment: So, it means if there are a lot of spaces freed by major GC, without resetting size configuration, the spaces cannot be reused by young generation?

Comment: The space can be reused. Just thiking of moving a file from disk C to Disk D. Disk C free the file's space for next store.

Comment: Thanks @lichengwu. I think we have to make some JVM configuration change in order for free space in old generation to be used in young generation? Like the option of -Xmx and -Xms you give?